# Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: C

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

> I'm working with cocos2dx 2.1.4 ndk-r8e.When I compile the
>   ./build_native.sh I get the error as show I have tryed to solve the
>   solution provide by googling but didnt helped can any one plz point
>   out the problem below:
>   [here is image](http://sdrv.ms/1a4FTYX)
>
> here is my build_native.sh file :

```
NDK_ROOT="C:\Users\Documents\Downloads\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r8e"
APPNAME="hellowWorld"

# options

buildexternalsfromsource=

usage(){
cat << EOF
usage: $0 [options]

Build C/C++ code for $APPNAME using Android NDK

OPTIONS:
-s  Build externals from source
-h  this help
EOF
}

while getopts "sh" OPTION; do
case "$OPTION" in
s)
buildexternalsfromsource=1
;;
h)
usage
exit 0
;;
esac
done

# paths

if [ -z "${NDK_ROOT+aaa}" ];then
echo "please define NDK_ROOT"
exit 1
fi

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
# ... use paths relative to current directory
COCOS2DX_ROOT="C:\Users\monika\AppData\Local\Temp\cocos2d-x-2.1.4\cocos2d-x-2.1.4"
APP_ROOT="C:\Users\monika\AppData\Local\Temp\cocos2d-x-2.1.4\cocos2d-x-2.1.4\monicahello"
APP_ANDROID_ROOT="C:\Users\monika\AppData\Local\Temp\cocos2d-x-2.1.4\cocos2d-x-2.1.4\monicahello\proj.android"

echo "NDK_ROOT = $NDK_ROOT"
echo "COCOS2DX_ROOT = $COCOS2DX_ROOT"
echo "APP_ROOT = $APP_ROOT"
echo "APP_ANDROID_ROOT = $APP_ANDROID_ROOT"

# make sure assets is exist
if [ -d "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets ]; then
    rm -rf "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi

mkdir "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets

# copy resources
for file in "$APP_ROOT"/Resources/*
do
if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    cp -rf "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi

if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi
done

# copy icons (if they exist)
file="$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets/Icon-72.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
fi
file="$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets/Icon-48.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
fi
file="$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets/Icon-32.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
fi


if [[ "$buildexternalsfromsource" ]]; then
    echo "Building external dependencies from source"
    "$NDK_ROOT"/ndk-build -C "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT" $* \
        "NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/source"
else
    echo "Using prebuilt externals"
    "$NDK_ROOT"/ndk-build -C "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT" $* \
        "NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the paths provided are wrong, if you are using windows then paths must be relative from cygwin, because they are with the forward slash (/) rather the backward () that is common in windows. So instead of adding path from C directory, go to cygwin and browse drives and go to the folder from there using cd command and at the directory of which you want path of type command pwd it will give you the exact path of that folder. Copy paste it here and done.